# Using Data Load Infile, terminal shows implemented, but no records were loaded into the table

Tags: mysql, macos, load-data-infile

I used `DATA LOAD INFILE` to load a txt file which is about 2.5MB. After I execute the query in MySql, it shows `0 rows effected`.
Is that related to the file size? But there is no error popped up.

My data import query is:

```sql
load data local infile 'trips.txt '
into table trips
columns terminated by ','
lines terminated by '/n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

After entering the above query, I got:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec) 
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I have used similar syntax to import another two files, which are fine.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe this one particular file has other lines or columns terminator?

Comment: 2.5MB isn't really extraordinarily large.  peterm's answer is probably correct, but if not you may also want to try specifying a full path to the file (although I would expect an error if the filename is wrong....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

or

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! My bad. Can't believe I spent 2 days on '\'